# problem when ajax method in jquery loads a html with the same script

Tags: jquery, ajax

and first of all sorry for my english.

I do a code that load content into a div, without refreshing the web, every link sends vars trought ajax and returns some html code into a . Because of this, every code that i load with ajax, returns again my script.

So, I do a jquery script with  $.ajax method like this:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php",
                dataType: "html",
                data: dataAenviar,
                beforeSend: function(){
                },
                complete: function(){

                },
                success: function(html){ 
                        $('#container).html(html);
                });
        });
```

Supose then than process.php return this script and then some html (really i return: html content without heads, body, etc, just html.

The problem is this: first time i work, too fine. second, third, the fourty is more slow, the 10º is an eternal wait, like if the script loaded and loaded and loaded. Trought google chrome bugzilla i can see blink the #container.

Someone can think better way to do this or solve this little inconvenience?

Ill thankful a lot :)

Thanks for all!!

Alejandra Vega

Comment: Hi,

What I assume is, You may probably calling this ajax script in some javascript event, so if you are able to show the code and some rendered html (html from browser's view source), some one can help in more better way

Comment: It would be nice to give more information. :)

Answer (score 0):

process.php should not be returning HTML, HEAD, etc... it should only return what would go inside BODY.

So simply do not output those things. Try something like...

```
url: "process.php?x=1",
```

in process.php:

```
if (@$_GET['x']){

  // do whatever you need to do ;)

} else {

  // code to print <HTML> and <HEAD> and <SCRIPT> etc...

}
```

Do you see? If this does not help please tell me why. But you do not need to keep calling a page that prints script tags and other headers every time.